# Trying to define the Lie bracket of two vector fields

Tags: function-construction, vector-calculus, differential-geometry

I am trying to define in the simplest possible way (only one coordinate system, no checking that variables are vectors, etc.) the Lie bracket of two vector fields in 3-space.

What is wrong with the following code ? It seems that Lie[a,b] is not understood by Mathematica as an expression of the same kind as a and b.

```
coo := {{x, y, z}}
Jac[v_] := D[v, coo]
Lie[v_, w_] := Jac[w[x, y, z]].v[x, y, z] - Jac[v[x, y, z]].w[x, y, z]
a[x_, y_, z_] := {1, 0, 0}; b[x_, y_, z_] := {0, 1, x^2}
Lie[a, b]
Lie[a, Lie[a, b]]
```

Comment: If you try the code, you will see that Lie[a,b] gives the correct answer, but Lie[a, Lie[a, b]] doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
coo := {{x, y, z}}
Jac[v_] := D[v, coo]
Lie[v_, w_] := Jac[w].v - Jac[v].w
a := {1, 0, 0}
b := {0, 1, x^2}

Lie[a, b]

{0, 0, 2 x}

Lie[a, Lie[a, b]]

{0, 0, 2}
```

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it:

```
a = {1, 0, 0};
b = {0, 1, x^2};

Jac[v_] := D[v, {{x, y, z}}];
Lie[v_, w_] := Jac[w].v - Jac[v].w;

Lie[a, b] (* {0, 0, 2x} *)
Lie[a, Lie[a, b]] (* {0, 0, 2} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with the following code:

```
LieBracket[field1_?VectorQ, field2_?VectorQ, vars_?VectorQ] := Module[{jac, lieb}, 
jac[field_?VectorQ, vars1_?VectorQ] := D[field, {vars}];
lieb = jac[field2, vars].field1 - jac[field1, vars].field2;
Return[lieb];];
```

Vector fields:

```
VF1 = {α y, -β x}; VF2 = {y x^2, -x y}; vars = {x, y};
a = {1, 0, 0}; b = {1, 1, x^2}; vars2 = {x, y, z};
```

Test 1:

```
LieBracket[VF1, VF2, vars]
(*{x y α + 2 x y^2 α - x^3 β, -y^2 α + x^2 β + x^2 y β}*)
```

Tes 2:

```
LieBracket[a, b, vars2]
(*{0, 0, 2 x}*)
LieBracket[a, LieBracket[a, b, vars2], vars2]
(*{0, 0, 2}*)
```

Test 3 (operator form):

```
Map[LieBracket[#[[1]], #[[2]], #[[3]]] &, {{VF1, VF2, vars}, {a, b, vars2}}]
(*{{x y α + 2 x y^2 α - x^3 β, -y^2 α + x^2 β + x^2 y β}, {0, 0, 2}}*)
```